# Ignore intermediate stderr inside a pipeline?

Tags: bash

Assume: `psA | psB | psC`

Sometimes one or several intermediate process output both stderr and stdout, and i just want clean stdout message.

Is there a way to ignore stderr inside pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

too easy :

```
psA 2> /dev/null | psB 2> /dev/null | ...
```

Comment: How about just after pipeline ?

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect the stderr of the whole pipeline to /dev/null.

```
{ psA | psB | psC; } 2>/dev/null
```